# Probability of drawing n distinct values out of {1,...,n^3}

Tags: probability

I draw uniformly at random $n$ values out of $\{1,...,n^3\}$.

I want to lowerbound the probability of getting $n$ distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the probability 
$$
\prod_{j=0}^n\left[1-\frac{j}{n^3}\right]
$$
and repeatedly using the relation that for $a,b>0$
$$
(1-a)(1-b) < 1-a-b
$$
we get a lower bound of 
$$
1 - \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{j}{n^3} = 1 - \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{j=0}^n j = 1 - \frac{n+1}{2n^2}  
$$
And of course there is an upper bound of $1$.

Answer (score 0):

To meet your expectations your first number could be any number in the original set, that is, you can make it in $n^3$ different ways. Your second number cannot be the first one so you can meet your expectations only in $n^3-1$ different ways. Your $i$-th number cannot be the $(i-1)\text{-th},(i-2)\text{-th},...$ numbers, so you can choose from $n^3-i+1$ numbers.

So the probability should be

$$\prod_{j=0}^n\frac{n^3-j}{n^3}=\prod_{j=0}^n\left[1-\frac{j}{n^3}\right].$$

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to choose $n$ distinct items out of $n^3$ distinct items is:

$$\binom{n^3}{n}=\frac{(n^3)!}{(n!)(n^3-n)!}$$

The number of ways to choose $n$ non-distinct items out of $n^3$ distinct items is:

$$(n^3)^n=n^{3n}$$

Therefore, the probability of choosing $n$ distinct items out of $n^3$ distinct items is:

$$\frac{(n^3)!}{(n!)(n^3-n)!(n^{3n})}\approx\frac{n^{(3n^3-4n-\frac{1}{2})}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(n^3-n)^{(n^3-n)}}$$

Comment: I would recommend using Stirling's approximation at this point to get a more useful answer than $(n^3)!$.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Thanks. Your suggestion is very constructive, and I have done so indeed. But the result doesn't make it much simpler to analyze, and I am not even certain that I haven't made a mistake while simplifying it, so I will most likely delete the answer. Edit: after testing with WolframAlpha, it seems a correct approximation (after simplifying the original one).